# Get users who voted on a post

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
|posts|          |votes|
 ----              ----
id                id
content           post_id
                  user_id
                  voted
```

Essentialy what I'm looking to do is retrieve all the posts in the database alogn with an extra field `voted` that will show if the user voted on that post.

So I want to pull `content` from `posts` and `voted` from `votes`.

Say the current user has id `2`. I tried to do something like (pseudo SQL syntax)

```
SELECT 
  posts.content,
  votes.voted
FROM 
  posts
  LEFT JOIN votes ON posts.id = votes.post_id
WHERE votes.user_id = 2
```

This works fine on posts the user has already voted on and there is a matching record in votes table, however **posts the user hasn't voted on won't be displayed** which makes sense but don't know how to circumvent this , I would like `voted` in this case to be `NULL`. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Put your predicate `votes.user_id = 2` into the join clause rather than the `WHERE`. At present your where clause effectively turns your left outer join into an inner join, because in any rows where there is no vote then `user_id` will be `NULL`, and `NULL = 2` evaluates to `NULL`, so the row is filtered out.

Comment: ^^ right. Having it in `WHERE` effectively turns your `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By checking the `votes.user_id` in the `WHERE` clause, you're *effectively* turning your join into an `INNER JOIN`.

You could just move it as a clause on the join, so something like:

```
SELECT      posts.content, 
            votes.voted 

FROM        posts 

LEFT JOIN   votes 
    ON      posts.id = votes.post_id 
    AND     votes.user_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that while your join allows for the vote to not be present, your where clause does not.

Change your query to this, so that the join is dependent on the user as well.

```
SELECT posts.content, votes.voted 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN votes ON posts.id = votes.post_id AND votes.user_id = 2
```